# How to setup VisualSVN Setup on Windows Azure Instance

Tags: svn, azure, version-control, visualsvn-server

I have used RDP to get into my windows azure instance.  I downloaded VisualSVN Server for Windows and have installed it and created a repository.  My problem is setting up my domain or ip that I am suppose to connect to to reach the repository.  I used my cloudapp.net url, I also binded my IP into the settings of the VisualSVN IP addresses.  I am using port 443, and using secure connection (https://).  Ive tried connecting to the following address to reach my repository:

https://****encryptcode****.cloudapp.net/svn/myrepository

https://****server ip****/svn/myrepository

Everytime I get this error in my visual studio:
`"Repository is not available.  Request was failed with the following message..."`

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Hi - I might have misunderstood your question but it reads to me that you are looking to run SVN in Azure and you have enabled RDP on a machine logged into that machine, installed VisualSVN (I presume Visual Studio too or maybe this is a VM Role) and now you want to access it publicly from your on-premise machines?

Comment: correct! sorry if i was not clear

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't finish the post, put it as an answer!!

Comment: Marco Pasin's guide in the answer below looks good, and now there's an alternative, and somewhat newer, guide here: http://microsoft.opennessatcee.com/azureboxes/2016/02/27/svn-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your question but it reads to me that you are looking to run SVN in Azure and you have enabled RDP on a machine logged into that machine, installed VisualSVN (I presume Visual Studio too or maybe this is a VM Role) and now you want to access it publicly from your on-premise machines?

Azure is a stateless PaaS Platform where machine state is not stored, every time your Azure instance recycles you will go back to 'day one' the stateless program or VMRole you uploaded. This wouldnt really be the place to run SVN?

Mary Jo Foley does make reference to a persisted state VM which might better meet your requirements in the future http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-to-enable-linux-on-its-windows-azure-cloud-in-2012/11508?tag=mantle_skin;content

MSFT do offer TFS as a Service on Azure for a persistent code repository which is currently in CTP http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/14/team-foundation-server-on-windows-azure.aspx

Not sure if this helps, sorry if I'm way off the mark :)

Comment: From memory SVN is file based, maybe you can store the code in Blob Storage and have it persisted there, I wonder has anyone done this and if it works (or more to the point supported!)

Answer (score 6):

The new [Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/virtual-machines/) feature now adds persistence to the instances deployed on Windows Azure, at the price of requiring more direct management of the machine (e.g.: updates, settings, ...). VisualSVN can now be installed and run on a cloud located Windows Server (2008 R2 SP1 or 2012) Azure VM. [Here](http://mictorino.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/visualsvn-on-azure-vm/) a quick start guide is available with some setup tips.

Comment: Hey Marco! Thank you for the great guide! http://mictorino.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/windowsazure_visualsvnquickstart.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a little trick to access SVN repository on Azure VM.

1. Add azure endpoint (port 8443, Name VisualSVN as tcp protocol) on azure Server VM. You can do it from azure portal. (assume familiar with the process)
2. Install VisualSVN server and configure to run on 8443 port. you can customize it later also.Follow next.

3.Open VisualSVN Server Manager and open properties(right click and properties).

4. Goto Network tab and append ".cloudapp.net" in server name field if not added already and update Server port to 8443.
5. Apply changes and restart VisualSVN server manually if not restarted automatically.

That's all.

Now you can browse on client by https://.cloudapp.net:8443/svn/

Answer (score -1):

Anything installed on your Azure instance BY RDPing will be lost whenever Azure recycles your instance. In short you will loose your repository.