# How to back up code online using SVN

Tags: java, svn, version-control, backup

I want to back up my code online and I tried using subversion with a visual SVN Server. It says (local) on visual SVN. Does this mean that if my computer breaks I would lose everything? What should I do to back it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Subversion is a version-control system, i.e. a time machine for your code, not a backup tool. While SVN can act as a backup system, it provides much more than just backups and opposed to Git -- Subversion is a *real time machine* where you can revert to a particular point in time and see your code as it was in 2012/02/11 02:11AM.

It's awkward not to use a version-control system in 2014. VCS can be your best friend which will help you a lot after you learn how to use it. You may want to learn more about version-control by reading the [Bible of Subversion -- SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/).

---

- VisualSVN Server is installed on your machine locally, so if you lose your computer (i.e. hardware malfunction leading to complete data loss) then your versioned data is lost. To ensure your code is safe, [you can configure VisualSVN Server to work with repositories which are hosted on a network share (e.g. NAS device)](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00022/) and consider making scheduled backups of your repos. Using a USB drive to host your repos is also a solution but for "one-man dev team" only.
- You can [install VisualSVN Server on a Windows Azure virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14362755/761095).
- You can try some hosted Subversion solution, however I'd avoid it. Recent attack on [CodeSpaces](https://www.codespaces.com/) makes me think that using shared hosting for source code is not the best choice for anyone.

Comment: Although then you could just put the code on the network share (if you're not using any other SVN features, like the OP doesn't seem to be)

Comment: @immibis tags include [svn] and he mentions VisualSVN Server in question, so I wanna give him complete answer on this matter. BTW, not using version-control nowadays is awkward.

Answer (score 1):

SVN (Subversion) is a version control system, not necessarily a backup system (though it can function as that).  The fact that it says "local" refers to the location of the server - in this case, it sounds like it's on your computer.  So yes, if your computer breaks, you would theoretically lose everything.

If you want to back it up using a server located elsewhere (which would be "remote", not "local"), you either need to find an SVN server elsewhere for such a purpose (of which I'm admittedly not too familiar) or use another similar type of software.  Another possibility is using Git, which was developed by Linus Torvalds for the Linux kernel, and signing up for a free account at Github (https://github.com/).  Note that if what you're working on is proprietary, you may need to pay for a private repository.

Alternatively, if you'd like to keep using SVN, you can set up a server on an old computer; if all you're trying to do is back up your code, however, SVN or Git might be overkill - a good thumb drive will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. I'll probably save it on a thumb drive.